# Can I output a result that if clicked send me to another document?

Tags: python, hyperlink, output

i am trying to find some synthetic numbers that summarize some test that I am performing on a Neural Network, and I was wondering if it was possible to create some outputs that if clicked on would send to another documents where more detailed information would be given about the experiment.

Comment: What do you mean by clicked on ? Like a link to another more detailed file inside a "summary result file" ?

Comment: Yes, like when you click on a link and gets you to a webpage.In this case clicking on the value would open instead of a webpage another more detailed file

Comment: Well, this is more likely a behavior of the program you use to see the content of a file. The easiest way would probably be to output a html file with a hyperlink to another file in it.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try this way!